# How to perform insertion with one to one mapping in hibernate

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate

I have successfully created a one-to-one mapping between two entities. I am able to retrieve data from the two tables, however I am failing to perform an insertion.

```
@Entity
@Table(name="users_test")
public class User {
    @Id
    @Column(name="user_id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int id;
    private String username;
    private String password;
    private int enabled;

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn
    private UserRole userRole;

       //getters and setters
}
```

---

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "user_roles")
public class UserRole {
    private int user_role_id;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "gen")
    @Column(name = "user_id", unique = true, nullable = false)
    @GenericGenerator(name="gen", strategy="foreign", parameters=@Parameter(name="property", value="user"))
    private int user_id;
    private String authority;

    @OneToOne(mappedBy="userRole", cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    private User user;

        //getters and setters
}
```

I was successfully able to read values from the tables via this mapping, however when I try to insert data into the tables I get an error.

```
public class Runner {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Runner run = new Runner();
        ApplicationContext context = new FileSystemXmlApplicationContext("E:\\applicationContext.xml");

        UserDao userDao = (UserDao) context.getBean("userDao");


        UserRole userRole = new UserRole();
        userRole.setAuthority("USER_ROLE");
        userRole.setUser_role_id(0);

        User user = new User();
        user.setUsername("ichigo");
        user.setPassword("kura");
        user.setEnabled(0);
        user.setUserRole(userRole);
        userDao.insertUser(user);
    }

}
```

UserDao:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
@Repository
@Transactional
public class UserDao {
    @Autowired
    SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    public List<User> getUsers() {
        Session currentSession = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        return currentSession.createQuery("from User").list();
    }

    public void insertUser(User user) {
        sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().save(user);
    }
}
```

I get the following exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.id.IdentifierGenerationException: attempted to assign id from null one-to-one property [test.hibernate.model.UserRole.user]
    at org.hibernate.id.ForeignGenerator.generate(ForeignGenerator.java:101)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:118)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:204)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:189)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.performSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:114)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.onSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:90)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireSaveOrUpdate(SessionImpl.java:724)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.saveOrUpdate(SessionImpl.java:716)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.CascadingAction$5.cascade(CascadingAction.java:258)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeToOne(Cascade.java:380)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeAssociation(Cascade.java:323)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeProperty(Cascade.java:208)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascade(Cascade.java:165)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.cascadeAfterSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:448)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSaveOrReplicate(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:293)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:193)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:126)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:204)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(DefaultSaveEventListener.java:55)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:189)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveEventListener.performSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveEventListener.java:49)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.onSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:90)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireSave(SessionImpl.java:753)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.save(SessionImpl.java:745)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.save(SessionImpl.java:741)
    at test.hibernate.dao.UserDao.insertUser(UserDao.java:24)
    at test.hibernate.dao.UserDao$$FastClassByCGLIB$$192f03a.invoke(<generated>)
    at net.sf.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:191)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.Cglib2AopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(Cglib2AopProxy.java:689)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:110)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.Cglib2AopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(Cglib2AopProxy.java:622)
    at test.hibernate.dao.UserDao$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$7428e072.insertUser(<generated>)
    at test.hibernate.test.main.Runner.main(Runner.java:34)
```

Please advice on what am I doing wrong.

---

**EDIT:**

It seems from the replies that I have my foreign keys mixed up in the code. So just make the question clear, I am posting the schema of the tables.

```
    CREATE TABLE `users_test` (                              
                  `USER_ID` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,    
                  `USERNAME` varchar(45) NOT NULL,                       
                  `PASSWORD` varchar(45) NOT NULL,                       
                  `ENABLED` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,                         
                  PRIMARY KEY (`USER_ID`)                                
                ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=113 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8  

CREATE TABLE `user_roles` (                                                                                                   
              `USER_ROLE_ID` int(10) DEFAULT NULL,                                                                                        
              `USER_ID` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,                                                                                        
              `AUTHORITY` varchar(45) NOT NULL,                                                                                           
              PRIMARY KEY (`USER_ID`),                                                                                                    
              KEY `FK_user_roles` (`USER_ID`),                                                                                            
              CONSTRAINT `FK_user_roles` FOREIGN KEY (`USER_ID`) REFERENCES `users_test` (`USER_ID`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE  
            ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Comment: Why do yo annotate the foreign key user_id with @Id ?

Comment: I constructed the above from here....http://howtodoinjava.com/2012/11/15/hibernate-one-to-one-mapping-using-annotations/ .... the one with Using shared primary key example

Comment: There are lots of messy things in this code (not in tutorial, in the question). What is your owing site of the relation. It seems it is User. If so, foreign key is also in wrong table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your one to one mapping is also wrong, foreign key are not used properly. In your example, there is wrong usage of foreign keys. Your mapping says that `primary key` of `UserRole` is `foreign key` in `User`, but it is not. You need to remove `@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn` and map foreign key with `@JoinColumn`

There are 2 types of one to one mapping.

**Unidirectional Mapping**

Only owing side of the object is mapped in relations. Object is not appear in the other side of relation.

```
@Entity
@Table(name="users_test")
public class User {
    @Id
    @Column(name="user_id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int id;
    private String username;
    private String password;
    private int enabled;

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
    private UserRole userRole;

       //getters and setters
}
```

And `UserRole` class will not have any `User` since bidirectional mapping is used.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "user_roles")
public class UserRole {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "gen")
    @Column(name = "user_role_id", unique = true, nullable = false)
    @GenericGenerator(name="gen", strategy="foreign", parameters=@Parameter(name="property", value="user"))
    private int user_role_id;
    private String authority;

}
```

**Bidirectional Mapping**

Both classes have the relations in this mapping style. `mappedBy` attribute used here to emphasize owing side of the relation. There no need second foreign key, just add `User` object to `UserRole` with proper mapping. It is mapped by `user` not `userRole` in your case.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "user_roles")
public class UserRole {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "gen")
    @Column(name = "user_role_id", unique = true, nullable = false)
    @GenericGenerator(name="gen", strategy="foreign", parameters=@Parameter(name="property", value="user"))
    private int user_role_id;
    private String authority;

    @OneToOne(mappedBy="user", cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    private User user;

        //getters and setters
}
```

**Edit**

There is another wrong mapping. `UserRole#user_role_id` is your foreign key which is annotated with `@Id`.

Comment: when i used the unidirectional version... i am able to retrieve the tables correctly

Comment: however the insertional fails with a NPE.... is it because of the foreign key issue?

Comment: If owing side of relation is User. I mean User has Roles. your tables are also wrong. Mapping says User is the owing side while tables say UserRole is owing.

Comment: For the unidirectional case, what is the `user` in `@Parameter(name="property", value="user")` referencing?

Answer (score 0):

You have a bi-directonal relationship but are only setting one side of the relation ship. You are only doing `user.setUserRole(userRole)`. You need to do a `userRole.setUser(user)` to, I favor doing this inside the setter for `setUserRole()`

```
public clas User {

    public void setUserRole(UserRole userRole) {
        this.userRole=userRole;
        this.userRole.setUserRole(this);
    }

}
```

This way it is always handled. (You might need/want to add a `null` check also).

One more weird thing in your code why does your `UserRole` object have a `User` and a `user_id` field? It should, IMHO, only have a `User` field.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "user_roles")
public class UserRole {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int user_role_id;

    private String authority;

    @OneToOne(mappedBy="user", cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    private User user;

    //getters and setters
}
```

I would expect something like the above.

Comment: There is no need to set both sides of relation. it depends on the owing side of relation. If owing side of relation is `User` then `UserRole`nedded to be set, or owing side is `UserRole` then `User` should be set.

Comment: My experience the last couple years with Hibernate and not setting both sides of a bi-directional relationship is that hibernate often gets confused. Hence better be safe and set both sides, this is also better in terms of OO, that you should set both sides of the relationship.

Answer (score -1):

Firstly, from what I can interpret, that one-to-one mapping between User and Role entity is incorrect.  You might want your user to have more that one roles right?

The UserRole entity should not have reference back to User - UserRole can exist without User.

One User can have many Roles and one role can be assigned to many User. (Assuming this is what you intend to do.)

I would suggest you to use unidirectional many-to-many or  relationship between User & UserRole enttity. It will create a seperate table for User-UserRole mapping.

Example:-

```
class User {

     //  ID and other fields


     @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
     @JoinColumn(unique = false, nullable = false, name = "ROLE", insertable = true)
     @Fetch(value = FetchMode.JOIN)
     @JoinTable(name="USER_ROLE_MAPPING")
     private List<UserRole> authorities;
}
```

The role entity:-

```
class UserRole{

     // id and other fields.

      private String roleName;    // Thats it !!
}
```

Comment: There is OneToOne mapping here. There is a UserRole for a User. Furthermore, ıt can be seen in the OP's code, there is bidirectional mapping. I really do not understand why you suggest ManyToMany. I can not see any about it in the question.

Comment: Yes I know that the question describes about OneToOne mapping. I gave my 'opinion' on not having it that way altogether. In most user & role scenario, that is the case. Down voting wasn't really required. Anyways...