# Hibernate List Mapping Annotation

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, jpa-2.0, hibernate-annotations

Well i have this problem

These are my tables [image]

this is my code for "Compra"

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "compra")
public class Compra implements Serializable {

     @Id
     @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
     @Column(name = "codigo", unique = true, nullable = false)
     private int codigo;

     @ManyToOne
     @JoinColumn(name = "codProveedor", nullable = false)
     private Proveedor proveedor;

     @Column(name = "tipoComprobante", nullable = false)
     private String tipoComprobante;

     @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
     @Column(name = "fechaFactura", nullable = false)
     private Date fechaFactura;

     @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
     @Column(name = "fechaLlegada", nullable = false)
     private Date fechaLlegada;

     @Column(name = "serie", nullable = false)
     private String serie;

     @Column(name = "numero", nullable = false)
     private int numero;

     @Column(name = "importe", nullable = false)
     private double importe;

     @Column(name = "vigencia", nullable = false)
     private boolean vigencia = true;

     @ElementCollection    
     private List<DetalleCompra> lstDetalle = new ArrayList<DetalleCompra>();
    // getters and setters ...
```

And this is my code for "DetalleCompra"

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "detalleCompra")
public class DetalleCompra implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "gen")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "gen", strategy = "foreign", parameters =       @Parameter(name  = "property", value = "compra"))
    @Column(name = "codCompra", nullable = false)      
    private int codCompra;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "codPresentacion", nullable = false)
    private Presentacion presentacion;

    @Column(name = "imei", nullable = false)
    private String imei;

    @Column(name = "simcard", nullable = false)
    private String simcard;
    getters and setters ...
```

Well everything looks fine, but when i want to save i have this problem

***org.hibernate.TransientObjectException: object references an unsaved transient instance – save the transient instance before flushing: DetalleCompra***

well it is clear because when i want to save Compra and DetalleCompra, the second table expect the fk value

```
  public void registrar(Compra compra) {
    try {
        session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
        trans = session.beginTransaction();                      
        session.save(compra);
        trans.commit();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        trans.rollback();
        throw e;
    } finally {
        session.close();
    }
}
```

Well the pk of table "compra" is generated well but for the other table does not recognized this value autogenerated, why?, how can i solve that?

Comment: why '@ElementCollection'  and not '@OneToMany'

Comment: when i put onetomany it said the same "org.hibernate.TransientObjectException: object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing: DetalleCompra"

Answer (score 0):

> @ElementCollection
>
> Defines a collection of instances of a basic type or embeddable class.
>   Must be specified if the collection is to be mapped by means of a
>   collection table.

You use wrong annotation to represent relation. There is one to many relation between `Compra` and  `DetalleCompra`.

You should change `@ElementCollection` annotation to `@OneToMany`. Do not forget to specify join columns `@JoinColumn(name="codCompra")`. I assume that `Presentacion` is properly mapped.

**See also**

[Unidirectional Mapping vs. Bidirectional Mapping](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18864976/892994)

[mappedBy attribute](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/persistence/OneToMany.html)

[@OneToMany annotation](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/persistence/OneToMany.html)

[@ElementCollection annotation](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/ElementCollection.html)

Comment: yeah i know, thanks but also when i put OneToMany it said this again:

org.hibernate.TransientObjectException: object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing: DetalleCompra

Comment: use `@JoinColumn(name="codCompra")` after `@OneToMany`

Comment: it said the same, i thinks  @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL) will help, but i have a null error when i put that